# How can be give a number (id) to a leads in Openerp.?

Tags: odoo

How can be give lead number in the Openerp v7.0 .

I want to give an identification numbers to my leads in Openerp . How can i make it possible ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the crm_lead.py file like this

write the function like this.

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if vals.get('x_name_lead','/')=='/':
        vals['x_name_lead'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'crm.lead') or '/'
    return super(crm_lead, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

Then create a new a sequence in the Settings->configuration->sequence->sequence & identifiers.

The edited the tree view of the lead Add a new field "x_name_lead" with char field. The corresponding field will be added on crm.lead model.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence for it like Sale order, Purchase order, etc. You will get many such examples in OpenERP. They all are working well.

Comment: hi i got an example for saleorder sequence generation . As a new person in openerp i have a doubt . in which py file and xml file i make edited (where i call the create without name ).

Comment: You need to create a new Sequence in xml file with your Prefix and number whatever you want to assign to lead and get that sequence in py file in _defaults of lead object.